# IIS settings to receive a custom HTTP Header

Tags: xml, http, iis, asp-classic, upload

I have a problem,
i have to receive an xml file (multipart form data) to my web site from a software, but the problem is that they send me a custom HTTP HEADER (HTTP_X_AUTHORIZATION) and when i receive the file is not correct but this is the result:

```
ntent-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

i can't use this xml file, i read that i need to set my IIS to receive this type of custom header.
Someone know how???

Answer (score 0):

Assuming IIS 6.0

Open IIS Manager and browse down the tree on the left until you see your web application.

- Open Control Panel
- Open Administrative Tools
- Open Internet Information Services
- In the left hand panel, expand <*Your Server*>
- Expand Web Sites

Right-click to open the context menu for this, and click Properties. The dialog that opens has a series of tabs across the top, choose the fourth one "HTTP Headers". You can add a Custom Header here. From your HTTP Header, your Header Name should be "HTTP_X_AUTHORIZATION" and its value should be "c2Npcm9jY286Y29udHJvbGxv". Click OK twice to save your settings.

IIS 7.0

In this version you can add a setting in your Web.config file that achieves the same thing.

```
    <!-- 
        Other stuff found here -->

  <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
        <add name="HTTP_X_AUTHORIZATION" value="c2Npcm9jY286Y29udHJvbGxv" />
     </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

See http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders for 
more info. Jim McGoldrick, cablesafe.co.uk

Comment: can i have an example? the param i receive in HTTP HEADER is like that:
`HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH:716
HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE:multipart/form-data; boundary=--------061412162232828
HTTP_ACCEPT:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING:identity
HTTP_USER_AGENT:Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)
HTTP_X_AUTHORIZATION:c2Npcm9jY286Y29udHJvbGxv`